# What does `_` do, in `printf (_("abc"));`, present in gnu-dd's code, but gcc giving me errors, and warning

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, dd

Im reading the source code of the gnu's dd command, but noticed a weird symbol.

NOTE: all below mentioned code, is compiled on latest gcc, on arch GNU/Linux on physical(not VM) amd64,

[At](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/dd.c#L544), the statement `printf (_("abc"));`, is giving

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

along with

```
undefined reference to `_'`
```

error, and program returning status 1, on my computer, same for `fputs`s below that statement

Comment: Please show *complete* error messages in separate code paragraph, rather than formatted as inline code. Inline formatting is messing up with the special characters.

Comment: @gitman-2021 Looks like it is a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is defined in `system.h`:179,

```c
#define _(msgid) gettext (msgid)
```

(how did I find this: open dd.c in neovim, move cursor to the `_` in question, run `:lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()`)

So, that puts the message through the GNU `gettext` string translator.

(two cents on coding style: Generally, try to avoid using such extremely short macros as `_`, and use proper functions if possible. All that `_` being a macro does is save typing 6 characters at the cost of obscuring what happens. IMHO, a bad terseness/readability tradeoff. When you look at GNU coreutils mailing lists, you'll find me contradict coreutil's approach to macros more widely. I'll say that it's a very mature code base, going back to at least 1992, and you definitely notice that in the coding style. I probably wouldn't recommend writing C in 2023 as most of coreutils looks like)

Comment: Using `_` to refer to `gettext` is an *extremely widely used*, long-established convention in C. I would generally agree with your concerns but then the same concern affects C syntax in general (it makes many of the same, bad decisions). It's firmly established. That said, beccause of this `_` should really *never* be used for anything else in C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well I know it from a few GNU projects, indeed; I didn't know it was *widely* used (I've honestly not seen it outside of GNU C projects… but then again, if I read C, it's usually targeting unhosted environments, not something where you have gettext-translated string output on). That being said, and agreeing with you, *generally* you would, as anyone developing new software, avoid introducing new variants of `_` or similarly short macros / symbols.

Comment: *"move cursor to the _"* ---> Would it work in plain vim? I don't have it at hand to check. :)

Comment: @Haris nope, the Lua interface and LSP integration are two of the main features setting neovim apart from old vim.

Comment: @Haris ctags will probably find it.

Comment: @Shawn wow, ctags… it's been a while! yeah, for simple macros as this, a ctags run should probably list the macro, so that would work. (From someone having used vim since ca 2008: LSP + clangd is *much* better than ctags; I'd strongly recommend trying AstroNvim, https://astronvim.com/#clone-the-repository ; Install neovim through your package manager, `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/AstroNvim/AstroNvim ~/.config/nvim ; https://github.com/AstroNvim/user_example ~/.config/nvim/lua/user ; nvim  --headless -c 'quitall'` does all the heavy lifting.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph *Using `_` to refer to `gettext` is an extremely widely used, long-established convention in C*  That doesn't make it a good idea - **at all**.  If you don't already know that convention, how on God's good Earth are you going to find the definition?  `find /usr/include -type f | xargs grep _` is going to produce a mountain of data.  Finding the `_` definition/declaration in that morass of output is pretty much impossible.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Right, as I already alluded to in my comment the same argument can be levelled against C syntax in general; since you mention `grep` I could point out that C definitions are basically ungreppable (and as the answer shows, every decent IDE/editor has "go to definition" anyway). When working with C code bases you're expected to *know* C syntax, and the same is true for gettext conventions. I'm not defending this, I am just saying how it is.

Comment: @KonradRudolph agree with you, but honestly, even with a "go to definition" functionality, writing `_` instead of `gettext` is just unnecessary mental indirection :) Also, honestly, `coreutils` and `gnulib` have some of the most horribly nested macros I've seen from times before ca 1998, and you really need to make sure that your IDE "sees" exactly the same definitions as your build, otherwise your IDE *will* resolve the macro, but not how it is actually expanded at build time. It's a clustershambles, sometimes. Luckily, `#define _(msgid) gettext (msgid)` uses zero conditionals.

Comment: @KonradRudolph *the same argument can be levelled against C syntax in general*  But IMO that's a reason for not making things even harder - no one ever started programming already *knowing* C syntax.  And yes, lots of prehistoric idioms in C make things harder, but again IMO that's no reason to continue them.  And `grep` (along with experience...) can resolve dependencies faster and better than some IDEs... :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle sure, we can find IDEs that are worse than grep. Not really an argument for using a regular expression engine to do the job of a C tokenizer!